# Django: View only year in DateTimePicker widget

Tags: python, django, django-forms

If forms.py I have:

```
 self.fields['current_treatment_chelation_start']= forms.DateField(label=('Start of chelation therapy'),required=False,
    widget=DateTimePicker(options={"format": "YYYY",
                                   "pickTime": False,
                                   "startDate": "1900"}))
```

This shows me the date in calendar. I want the user to view only years and select one.

Any help?

Comment: If you only need the year, why not just use a `CharField` with year choices?

Comment: @Brandon DateTimePicker is a more user friendly widget.

Comment: Not for what you're wanting to do from a programmatic standpoint :)

Comment: try add option **viewMode: 'years'**

Comment: @madzohan When I click the calendar it show me to select a year, but when I select year it shows months and when I select months it shows me days. I only want to **view and select a year**.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using this package:

https://github.com/nkunihiko/django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker

You'll want to add this to your DateTimePicker options:

```
viewMode: 'years',
```

Comment: I added this and when I click the calendar it shows me to select a year, but when I select year it shows months and when I select months it shows me days. I only want to view and select a year.